# Can I set the start position from the Silder to e.g 9? Instead of 0?

Tags: python, tkinter, slider

currently I just try out some Stuff in Python. I did some stuff with Sliders, but I never found a command that I can set the Slider starting position to 9. Is there some command to the the Start pos?

Thank you in Advance

```
from tkinter import *

master = Tk()
Slider1 = Scale(master, from_=0, to=42, orient=VERTICAL, length=400)
Slider1.pack(side=left)

Slider2 = Scale(master, from_=0, to=200, orient=HORIZONTAL, length=400)
Slider2.pack()

Slider3 = Scale(master, from_=0, to=122, orient=HORIZONTAL,length=400)
Slider3.pack()

Slider4 = Scale(master, from_=0, to=30, orient=HORIZONTAL,length=400)
Slider4.pack()

Slider5 = Scale(master, from_=0, to=90, orient=HORIZONTAL, length=400)
Slider5.pack()

Slider6 = Scale(master, from_=90, to=150, orient=HORIZONTAL, length=400)
Slider6.pack()

mainloop()
```

Nothing worked for me so far

Comment: Did you try `Slider1.set(9)`?

Comment: Your code won't run as posted. Please make sure your code runs.

Comment: Slider1.pack(side=LEFT)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set the scale to any value you want with the `set` method:

```
Slider1.set(9)
```